# Creating resonation with lasers

Tags: science-based, physics

We know lasers right? Damn accurate, pew pew.... Meh. What I never saw, is using lasers to create pressure waves, to resonate something into its destruction. But Boeing even patented the [plan of a counter-measure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJ3isx3VRxM) that creates small exploding plasma bubbles, that protect against things like shockwaves (ya know, the things that can and will rupture your elastic blood vessels, causing internal bleeding.)

**sooo......**

### **Is it possible to create a sonic weapon, that is similar in working to Boeing's countermeasure?**

Comment: You got a source on the Boeing stuff?

Comment: @Mormacil Yep, I do.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Of course you can build a weapon like the one Boeing made...Boeing already patented it...

Comment: @kingledion on a site note, just because it got patented doesn't mean it works. Btw. it seems to be this patent if anyone wants to read it. https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?DB=EPODOC&II=1&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=en_EP&FT=D&date=20150317&CC=US&NR=8981261B1&KC=B1#

Comment: @DonQuiKong Granted. But I guess the point is that someone at both Boeing and the Patent Office think that it works, and they are probably better able to judge than anyone here.

Comment: @kingledion as long as it sounds reasonable the patent office doesn't care. Boeing I don't know, but for a big company a patent is cheaper than figuring out if that works.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible, but the boeing device works by creating a

> transient medium, different from the first medium, interposed between the shockwave and the protected region such that the shockwave contacts the second, transient medium and is attenuated in energy density before it reaches a protected asset in the protected region.

(https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/claims?CC=US&NR=8981261B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=3&date=20150317&DB=EPODOC&locale=en_EP#)

which means due to the different physical characteristics of the two mediums, the shockwave is reflected/weakend. The second medium (=shield medium) is created by having electric energy flow through a conductive path created by laser ionization (if I got that right) and heating the path.

To create a shockwave by heating air or another liquid with a laser, you'd need **a lot** of power. So much power, that aiming the laser directly at your opponent/target would be way more effective.

I'll leave the calculations to someone else.